# How Do I Resolve this MySQL Select Statement Error in VB.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using the following code in an attempt to retrieve data from two tables and populate a ComboBox with that information.  Then when the user selects a value from the ComboBox, I want to populate all the controls on the form with the data retrieved from the DB that matches the value of the ComboBox (still haven't figured out how to do this one yet).

**NOTE:**  The 1090 shown in the error is the account number I'm receiving from an InputBox control and then setting the TextboxAccount.Text value to it.  So I'm not sure if this is where my problem is.

**Here's the VB exception being thrown:**

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds with your MySQL version for the right syntax to use near
>   'customer.accountNumber = '1090" at line 1"

**Here's my code:**

```
    Private Sub RetrieveMySQLdata()

    Try
        'FOR MySQL DATABASE USE
        Dim dbConn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim dbQuery As String = ""
        Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand
        'Dim dbData As MySqlDataReader
        Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbTable As New DataTable
        If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            'dbConn = New MySqlConnection
            dbConn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Password={3};Database=accounting", FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem, My.Settings.DB_Port, My.Settings.DB_UserID, My.Settings.DB_Password)
            dbConn.Open()
        End If

        dbQuery = "SELECT *" & _
                   "FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber" & _
                   "WHERE customer.accountNumber = '" & TextBoxAccount.Text & "'"
        With dbCmd
            .CommandText = dbQuery
            .Connection = dbConn
        End With
        With dbAdapter
            .SelectCommand = dbCmd
            .Fill(dbtable)
        End With
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To dbTable.Rows.Count - 1
            ComboBoxCard.ValueMember = "cc_Number"

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                    vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Print out (or show somehow) the statement before you execute it. Should be pretty clear what the problem is

Comment: Mat, thanks for the offer to assist.  Based on David's response below, I discovered that I was missing a space just before the WHERE statement.  So I fixed it.  But now the ComboBox won't display the results of the query, and I'm pulling my hair out about that.....lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement:

```
dbQuery = "SELECT *" & _
          "FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber" & _
          "WHERE customer.accountNumber = '" & TextBoxAccount.Text & "'"
```

There's no space between some of the clauses, such as `cc_master.customer_accountNumber` and `WHERE`.  The resulting string would read like:

```
SELECT *FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumberWHERE customer.accountNumber = 'SOME SQL INJECTABLE STRING'
```

As a general hint with MySQL syntax error messages, when you see a message like this:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds with your MySQL version for the right syntax to use near 'customer.accountNumber = '1090" at line 1"

You should look *just* before the part that it's "near" to find the syntax error.  The query parser reads from beginning to end and throws an error when it finds something it can't interpret.  And usually the first thing it can't interpret is the first thing it sees after the typo/error.

**Please note also** that using string concatenation is a *very bad idea* for constructing SQL queries.  It leaves you wide open to [SQL injection attacks.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)  If you're using plain old ADO.NET, at the very least you should be using [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha.aspx).  As a step further, you may want to look into something like LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework which abstracts the database access behind auto-generated code which parameterizes for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks David, your answer helped me out.  I added a space the the exception is gone.  But the combobox isn't being populated with the information I want.  Perhaps I should open another question for that, eh?

Comment: @KismetAgbasi: That would indeed be better as another question, since altering the current question in such a way would invalidate existing responses.

Comment: Sorry I meant to add - also - that I am aware of the possibility of SQL Injection Attacks.  Unfortunately, I don't understand yet how to use LINQ or Entity Framework well enough.  I'm also just learning how to use parameters, and I struggle on the implementation.  So for now, since the application is only being used internally and is not connected to the Internet, I feel a bit safe.  Besides, my users are not that computer literate (they know the bare minimum to get their work done - so I'm sure they're not going to be injecting my server anytime soon).

Comment: @KismetAgbasi: Whether it's through malice or accident, a vulnerability is still a vulnerability.  I highly recommend learning the basics of SQL injection and making it a force of habit to try to prevent it.  Even if you're statistically safe, it's better to be explicitly safe.  And it's always a good thing to learn and adopt better coding habits, if for no other reason than to improve your own skills and further your career.

Comment: You're right David - I'm actually learning it.  I've used parametized queries elsewhere in my application, but it was with help from others on this site and I haven't been able to read through to really understand how they did it.  But I'm actively learning and hope to fully understand how to use such techniques soon, then I'll be explicitly safe as you've pointed out.